# Spherical Gravity rotation and position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a game using planet gravity physics. I'm stuck in rotating player.

```cs
 private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        ProcessInput();

        Vector3 gravityUp = (transform.position - gravityTarget.position).normalized;
        Vector3 bodyUp = transform.up;
        
        rb.AddForce(gravityUp * gravity);

        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(bodyUp , gravityUp) * transform.rotation;
        
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation , 50 * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        transform.rotation =targetRotation;


        Quaternion desRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDir);
        desRot = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, desRot , 360 * Time.deltaTime);


        transform.rotation = desRot;

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + transform.TransformDirection(moveDir) * 15f * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void ProcessInput()
    {
        moveDir = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized;
    }
```

Lets say I pressed <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and wanted to player to go left and turn left at the same time. The problem is `transform.TransformDirection(moveDir)`. When I make the player turn to the left, player starts the move its left side instead of the world position. If I only use `moveDir` for positioning, it goes out of the world. How can I make this work?

[You can see the video here!](https://streamable.com/sb8o28)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: [Try this](http://answers.unity.com/answers/46870/view.html)

Comment: I've already did this. Sadly it does not work because of transform.TransformDirection(moveDir).

Comment: Problems like this are usually managed by using different coordinate spaces. I think your planetary coordinates should be possible to describe with a single Quaternion, the movement direction should also be possible to describe as a rotation. Once done you should be able to convert your quaternion back to a world position.